# How to passed the selected comboxbox respective value in textbox in php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

i need to pass the value on the selection of combo box into the textbox.every value in the combox box has its own value that will be display  on the user selction in the text box.i do this but its displying nthng .kindly help me in this.

coding

```
 <?php

    $options = array(
        '0' => array(
            'title' => '-- Select',
            'value' => ''
        ),
        '1' => array(
            'title' => 'A',
            'value' => '300'
                        'value1' => '600'
        ),
        '2' => array(
            'title' => 'B',
            'value' => '1800'
                        'value1' => '900'
        ),
    );

    if (isset($_GET['option']) && isset($options[$_GET['option']])) {
        echo $options[$_GET['option']]['value'];
                 echo $options[$_GET['option']]['value1'];
        exit;
    }

?>
<select name="combo" id="combo">
<?php

    foreach($options as $key_value => $option) {
        printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $key_value, $option['title']);
    }

?>
</select>
<input type="text" name="hideen1" id="textboxB" value="" />
<input type="text" name="hideen1" id="textboC" value="" />


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){
        $('#combo').change(function(){
            $.get("?", {
                option : $(this).val()
            }, function (data) {
                $('#textboxB').val(data);
                                $('#textboxC').val(data);
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

For example

if user select `A` then in textbox1 `300` will appear and  in textbox2 `600` will appear. if select `B` then `100` will appear and in textbox2 `900` will appear. kindly help me in this.Plz kindly help me .I am gettng both values in both textboxes.

Comment: Is there a reason you are setting the value of the options in the select to be used as a key on the other page. Could you not set the value of the options to the values you need. Then take the value from the option and use that to update the text field.

Comment: no sir i need to explicity mention the values, i dont get values in the text box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood it right, but this should work.

Example for the original question on PhpFiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/rha-57n

**Updated** example **with 2 inputs** on PhpFiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/t13-0kj

```
    $options = array(
        '0' => array(
            'title' => '-- Select',
            'value1' => '',
            'value2' => '',     
        ),
        '1' => array(
            'title' => 'A',
            'value1' => '300',
            'value2' => '600',
        ),
        '2' => array(
            'title' => 'B',
            'value1' => '1800',
            'value2' => '900',          
        ),
    );

    if (isset($_GET['option']) && isset($options[$_GET['option']])) {
        echo json_encode($options[$_GET['option']]);
        exit;
    }


?>
<select name="combo" id="combo">
<?php

    foreach($options as $key_value => $option) {
        printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $key_value, $option['title']);
    }
?>
</select>
<input type="text" name="hideen1" id="textboxB" value="" />
<input type="text" name="hideen1" id="textboxC" value="" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){
        $('#combo').change(function(){
            $.getJSON("?", {
                option : $(this).val()
            }, function (data) {
                $('#textboxB').val(data.value1);
                $('#textboxC').val(data.value2);
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: sir i need to ask one thig more if i want in second text box to display the value mean on clickng 'A' In textbox1 its display 300 n in textbox2 its disply 400 .how i could ths